# why java.Lang.System can be used as a static class

Tags: java

When we invoke
 `System.out.println("aaa");`
 we are not instantiating an object of Class `System`.

And `System` is not a static class. In the document, it only says that `System` is `public final`.

So my question is why can we use `System` as a static class?

Comment: It has static fields and methods in it.

Comment: There is no such thing as a top level static class..

Comment: There's no such thing as a "static class" in Java. It's a class that has static fields/methods.

Comment: `System` is not a "static class" (that only makes sense in a whole different context), but `out` is a static member of the `System` class, so you can use it on the class directly. You can't use `System.toString()`, however, as that's **not** a static member.

Comment: @jlordo That still isn't a "static class"; it that context using the keyword `static` means the inner class can be used without an instance of the enclosing outer class being required.

Answer (score 1):

The System class contains several useful class fields and methods. It cannot be instantiated.

Among the facilities provided by the System class are standard input, standard output, and error output streams; access to externally defined properties and environment variables; a means of loading files and libraries; and a utility method for quickly copying a portion of an array.

If you check the api, all of its methods are static. And you are just accessing its public field `out` ...check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454866/out-in-system-out-println) for more info about when out is instantiated

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html

Answer (score 1):

The *class* isn't static, but the fields and methods within it are. You can still invoke static methods in this way.

Comment: To be precise: `out` is a field, not a method ;)

Answer (score 1):

Because `out` is a public static field on class `System`.  A static member can be accessed with the `Type.member` syntax.

In your example, you are calling the instance method `println()` as defined on `PrintStream`.  The invocation target is the `PrintStream` instance stored in the static field `System.out`.

Answer (score 0):

`System` is a top-level class. Since `out` is static (not `System itself), we use the syntax you describe.

The syntax for accessing a static class member is

> <class name>.<member name>

Note how this differs from accessing a non-static method or field:

> <object name>.<member name>

Note that the syntax is dictated by the staticness of the *member* of the class, not staticness of the class itself. In your example, the staticness of `System` is irrelavant; the staticness of `out` is what matters.