# Why "out" static field in System.out.println() doesn't throw null exception even though it is assigned null as final value in declaration?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jvm

I'm confused with the 'out' static field inside 'System' class, not throwing any nullpointer exception, even though it is assigned 'null' as final value in its declaration.

The statement is - "System.out.println();" - to understand this entire statement's implementation, I traced back to its implementation, using Eclipse IDE by pressing ctrl on the statement and clicking 'Open Declaration' option.

This how the 'out' static field is declared inside 'System' class.

```
public static final PrintStream out = null;
```

To check with this kind of implementation, I tried a very basic code, and the IDE did throw a NullPointerException.

The code I have tried is below

```
    public class examplo1 {
public static final TryingAnother sameTry = null;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    sameTry.addO();
    System.out.println();
}}
```

TryingAnother class code below

```
    public class TryingAnother {
int a = 25;

public void addO()
{
    a = a + 25;
    System.out.println(a);
}}
```

Thanks in advance for the answers!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9455073/17541296 The Answer to your question is described really well here.

Comment: Thanks @TimoHeinrich, it was helpful and explanation was well clear. May I know how to mark down this question as closed? Sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score -1):

System.out is the default outputstream which is normally the terminal. If it is declared as you have written, then the init is done by the JVM

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I got the answer from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9455073/17541296.